# Magento 2: Admin ui grid inline edit not working

Tags: magento2, ui-grid

I create admin ui grid and i want to add functionality of inline editable grid. But,  it's not working for me.

This is my `vendor_module_test_listing.xml` file code:

```
<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_test_listing.vendor_module_test_listing.vendor_module_test_columns.ids</item>
    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/inlineEdit"/>
        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

What I missing or do any mistake?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<item name="enabled">` value is false. First of all, set true value as like below :

**vendor_module_test_listing.xml :**

```
<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_test_listing.vendor_module_test_listing.vendor_module_test_columns.ids</item>
    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/inlineEdit"/>
        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Also, add this below code for clickable grid by field :

```
<item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_test_listing.vendor_module_test_listing.vendor_module_test_columns_editor</item>
    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
      <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </item>
  </item>
</item>
```

Now, create controller file `app\code\Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test\inlineEdit.php` :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Test\Collection;

/**
 * Grid inline edit controller file
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class InlineEdit extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $testCollection;

    /**
     * [__construct description]
     * @param Context     $context        [description]
     * @param Collection  $testCollection [description]
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory    [description]
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Collection $testCollection,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->testCollection = $testCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json $resultJson */
        $resultJson = $this->jsonFactory->create();
        $error = false;
        $messages = [];

        $postItems = $this->getRequest()->getParam('items', []);
        if (!($this->getRequest()->getParam('isAjax') && count($postItems))) {
            return $resultJson->setData([
                'messages' => [__('Please correct the data sent.')],
                'error' => true,
            ]);
        }

        try {
            $this->testCollection
                ->setStoreId($this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0))
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => array_keys($postItems)])
                ->walk('saveCollection', [$postItems]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $messages[] = __('There was an error saving the data: ') . $e->getMessage();
            $error = true;
        }

        return $resultJson->setData([
            'messages' => $messages,
            'error' => $error,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Now, update your column code as like below way :**

```
<column name="title">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <!-- inlineEdit code -->
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="validate-zero-or-greater" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
           <!-- End inlineEdit code -->
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Title</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

`<item name="editor" xsi:type="array"> .. </item>` is useful for make editable field.

Check this all requirements in your module.

Hope, it will helpful for you.

Comment: Happy to help ..!! Happy coding :)